# php curl with certificate and key file not connecting with swish payment api

Tags: php, curl, certificate, pem, swish

I need to implement Swish Payment e-commerce API with my website.
Testing code given by swish is working fine using Git Bash.
Sample is here

```
curl -s -S -i --cert ./Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1231181189.pem --key ./Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1231181189.key --cacert ./Swish_TLS_RootCA.pem --tlsv1.1 --header "Content-Type: application/json" https://mss.cpc.getswish.net/swish-cpcapi/api/v1/paymentrequests --data '{ "payeePaymentReference" : "0123456789", "callbackUrl" : "https://myfakehost.se/swishcallback.cfm", "payerAlias" : "4671234768", "payeeAlias" : "1231181189", "amount" : "100", "currency" : "SEK", "message" : "Kingston USB Flash Drive 8 GB" }'
```

but when i convert it in php it gives me error
cURL Error #:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

My php code is here

```
    $data = array(
    "content-type: application/json",
    "accept: application/json",
    "payeePaymentReference: 0123456789",
    "callbackUrl: https://myfakehost.se/swishcallback.cfm",
    "payerAlias: 4671234768",
    "payeeAlias: 1231181189",
    "amount: 100",
    "currency: SEK",
    "message: Kingston USB Flash Drive 8 GB"
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . '/Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1231181189.pem');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, getcwd() .'/Swish_Merchant_TestCertificate_1231181189.key');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD,  'swish');
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://mss.cpc.getswish.net/swish-cpcapi/v1/paymentrequests/',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($data),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "content-type: application/json"
  )
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

$err = curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
if ($err) {
   echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
   echo "Well:" .$response;
}
```

Comment: `--cacert ./Swish_TLS_RootCA.pem` is probably not optional …

Comment: @SakibAli did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the CA certificate.

Add the following curl option

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . './Swish_TLS_RootCA.pem');
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem here is that your php/libcurl defaulted to SSLv3, and that `mss.cpc.getswish.net` has turned off support for SSLv3 (most websites don't support it anymore because it's insecure),

1: you're running curl_setopt without error checking, fix that

2: you forgot to set CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 , fix that

```
if(!curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1)){
    throw new \RuntimeException('failed to set CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1');
}
```

- but given that your php/libcurl installation defaulted to SSLv3, your php installation is probably too old to use TLS1.1 anyway.. which means you probably need to update your php/libcurl installation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
using php version 7.2.5,
and use SSL_VERSION_TLSv1_1 but still showing error

Comment: By applying TLS version the error is fixed but now it giving me the error 
OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 104

Comment: @SakibAli what do you get from running `php -r 'phpinfo();' | pastebinit`  ?